# how to implement Laravel AJAX live search on CRUD management table?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a CRUD table that's holding records of doctors that get
retrieved from the MySQL database. I've been following a few tutorials
and managed to set up AJAX live results search.

Now the problem comes from the fact that the logic is stored in a
Controller. I can succesfully retrieve the details from the database
using '-- foreach($data as $row) --' but I don't know how to retrieve
the CRUD actions ( In this case  Delete.The create method is separated
from the table itself. I also can't implement status cell using i)

I've tried putting the actions inside the td'. .'td. tags but I get
Routing errors.

Any help is appreciated.

I have the code for the CRUD actions, images etc..inside
"index.blade.php". They should be somehow implemented in the
controller though.  doctor controller

```
  function liveSearchDoctor(Request $request)
        {
         if($request->ajax())
         {
          $output = '';
          $query = $request->get('query');
          
          if($query != '')
          {
            
            $data =Doctor::
                where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('mobile', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->paginate(2);
          
             
          }
          else
          {
            $data =Doctor::latest()->paginate(2);
          }
          $total_data = $data->count();
          if($total_data > 0)
          {
            foreach($data as $row)
            {
                $output .= '
                            <tr>
                                <td class="center"><img src="'.$row->image.'" style="width:40px;height:40px;"/></td>
                                <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row->department->name.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row->mobile.'</td>
                                //status should be implement here 
                                <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="'.route('doctors.edit',$row->id).'"><i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i></a>
                                //delete form should be implement here
    
                                
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            ';
            }
    
    
          }
          else
          {
           $output = '
           <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
           </tr>
           ';
          }
          $data = array(
           'table_data'  => $output,
           'total_data'  => $total_data
          );
    
          echo json_encode($data);
         }
        }
```

index.blade.php (( Note: The CRUD actions and everything is here
implemented succesfully. I however can't implement delete in the
controller )) here is the index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('css')

@endsection
@section('content')

<br>
<div class="br-pagebody">
   <div class="br-section-wrapper">
       @include('include._message')
   <div class="row">
       <h6 class="br-section-label">Doctors List</h6>
   </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4 ">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search doctor Data" />
           </div>
         </div>



         <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-5">
             <a href="{{route('doctors.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 35px">Add New Doctor</a>
         </div>
     </div>

   </br>
     
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-colored table-dark">
      <thead class="thead-colored thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Doctor Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>mobile</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>


        </thead>   
     <tbody>   
        @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
          <tr>
            <td class="center"><img src="{{URL::asset($doctor->image)}}" style="width:40px;height:40px;"/></td>
              <td class="center">{{$doctor->id}}</td>
              <td class="center">{{$doctor->name}}</td>
              <td class="center">{{$doctor->department->name}}</td>
              <td class="center">{{$doctor->email}}</td>
              <td class="center">{{$doctor->mobile}}</td>
                        
              <td class="center">
                  @if($doctor->status==1)
                      <span class="badge badge-success">Active</span>
                  @else
                      <span class="label label-danger">Deactive</span>
                  @endif
                  
              </td>
              <td class="center">
                 
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('doctors.edit',$doctor->id)}}">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i> 
                  </a>
                  
                  {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['doctors.destroy', $doctor->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
                  {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                  {!! Form::close() !!}
              </td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>  
    </div><!-- table-wrapper -->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      {!! $doctors->links() !!}
  </div>

  </div>
</div>

                      
        
@endsection
@section('js')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 fetch_doctor_data();

 function fetch_doctor_data(query = '')
 {
  console.log(query)
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{route('search.doctor')}}",
   method:"GET",
   data:{'query':query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
     console.log(data)
    $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
   }
  })
 }

 $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  var query = $(this).val();
  fetch_doctor_data(query);
 });
});
</script>
     
@endsection
```

Comment: Why would you process and put the data in the table in the controller? Why don't you do that in using javascript?

Comment: Actually i was following a tutorial about live search but there were  no action field  .How can i implement this using javascript can you help me please

Comment: so the controller successfully sends back the data and they get displayed on the table?

Comment: yes .I want to display the row in my table when the controller sends back the data